# Why voltage sensors are reading these values

Tags: transistors, voltage-measurement

I've tried to make the following circuit (both physically and simulated):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftZF1P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Not sure if its correct but below is the simulink model (same as physical one):
[image: Circuit modeled in simulink]

There is one thing I can't understand, I tried measuring voltage across R1 and R2, I though it would be the same, but instead as shown in simulink, the R2 voltage shows ~4.8V and R1 shows ~4.3V 
(on physical model multimeter has shown 5V and ~4.3V

Why would voltage across R1 be less 5V (4.3V) as if I was measuring the voltage drop on base-emitter of Q1?
On physical model the C4881 transistor was used. While on simulink some standard settings were there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your transistor is operating in saturation. Vbe is typically 0.6 or 0.7 volts, and Vce,sat is typically 200 mV.

So the the voltage across R1 is (5-Vbe) ~ 4.3 V.

The voltage across R2 is (5-Vcesat) ~ 4.8 V.